# How can I use the importhmtl function in combination with today ()-2 function?

Tags: google-sheets, importhtml

I am importing data from a website:
https://www.chancesgames.com/WinningNumbers/WinningList

It provides up to 30 days of data. I want only two days of data, specifically those in columns a, b, e, and d.

Here is the spreadsheet link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BRQO3lNuDXDYXujsDir5wo0xnQ49gzpomxw5zo2qctA/edit?usp=drivesdk

Answer (score 0):

To only show columns `A, B, D, E` in the rows where the date is between the dates you enter in cells `B1` and `C1`, use this formula:

```
=query( 
  importhtml("https://chancesgames.com/WinningNumbers/WinningList", "table", 1), 
  "select Col1, Col2, Col4, Col5 where Col1 is not null 
   and toDate(Col1) >= date '" & text(B1, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' 
   and toDate(Col1) <= date '" & text(C1, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' 
   and lower(Col2) matches '.*(" & lower(D1) & ").*' ", 
  1 
)
```

There is an additional keyword filter by the text string in cell `D1` that lets you enter a state name or some such search word that appears in the `House` name. Leave cell `D1` empty to show all rows between the two dates.

See the new [Solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BRQO3lNuDXDYXujsDir5wo0xnQ49gzpomxw5zo2qctA/edit#gid=1738291310) sheet in your sample spreadsheet.